# Updating firebase database in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to to update the entries in the table instead of replacing them.
The code I use currently:

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;  
    mDatabase =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(uid);
    HashMap<String,String> usermap = new HashMap<>();
    usermap.put("name",name);
    usermap.put("description",description);
    usermap.put("address",address);
    mDatabase.setValue(usermap);
```

removes the email field in Users I had in my database. I googled a bit and it turns out setValue replaces all the data. I tried using updateChildren instead but I get the error:DatabaseReference cannot be applied to `java.util.HashMap <java.lang.String,java.lang.String>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try something like:


mDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(uid);
    HashMap<String,Object> usermap = new HashMap<>(); // if you have data in diff data types go for HashMap<String,Object> or you can continue with HashMap<String,String>
    usermap.put("name",name);
    usermap.put("description",description);
    usermap.put("address",address);
    mDatabase.updateChildren(usermap); // Replace this line in your code to update.
```

Comment: Would there by any problem later on in using <String,Object> instead of <String,String>? name,description,address are all String type

Comment: In your case there won't be any but in future if you have data in diff data types go for HashMap<String,Object>

Comment: Main is " mDatabase.updateChildren(usermap);" hope you get your things done with this

Comment: It has worked! updateChildren gives me no error when I am using <String,Object>.There is only error when I use <String,String> Thanks. Will accept this answer in a few minutes.